# Нужна помощь в позиционировании фотографий

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.facebook{
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
}

.facebook img{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-middle">
    <div class="wraper">
        <footer>
        <div class="facebook">
            20000 Members
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/20f0cf900733d1ae312404c3bfb65126-full.png" alt="">
            <hr>
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/28/72730d3adcfc796a970f33b5ed13f630-full.png" alt="">
            <hr>
            facebook Social plugin
        </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Возникла проблема в позиционировании фотографий

Вот что получается у меня:

[image: Вот что получается у меня]

Вот тот результат, который хочу получить:

[image: То что хочу получить]

Comment: А зачем Вам верстать соц плагин от Фейсбука? Он же свой дает оформленный виджет.

Comment: @DaemonHK Да я новичок просто в этом деле и не знал этого((( В следующий раз буду знать))

Answer (score 3):

Например, так:

```css
.facebook {
  width: 480px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #3c3c3c;
}

.photo {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #3c3c9f;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebook">
  <div class="photo">1</div>
  <div class="photo">2</div>
  <div class="photo">3</div>
  <div class="photo">4</div>
  <div class="photo">5</div>
  <div class="photo">6</div>
  <div class="photo">7</div>
  <div class="photo">8</div>
</div>
```

Или так:

```css
.facebook {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 480px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #3c3c3c;
}

.photo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #3c3c9f;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebook">
  <div class="photo">1</div>
  <div class="photo">2</div>
  <div class="photo">3</div>
  <div class="photo">4</div>
  <div class="photo">5</div>
  <div class="photo">6</div>
  <div class="photo">7</div>
  <div class="photo">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще рекомендую изучить `flexbox` это упростит Вам работу с позиционированием элементов.

А вопросу. Задайте всех картинкам `float: left;`

А ещё лучше будет если Вы предоставите рабочий код в виде снипета.

Comment: Я немного пока в этом не шарю. А что такое сниппет?

Comment: @BraFik пример рабочего кода. который каждый человек может запустить тут же. Вы пишете свой html, css, js (если он есть) и он может запускаться.

Comment: @Tyklop Вроде бы добавил

Comment: @DogeDev Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

С помощью флоатов

```css
.panel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: 350px;
}

.panel li {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, #e3e3e3);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```